# how to update style attribute values programatically in android

Tags: java, android

I have a one style file which includes text color and text size attributes

I will change text color and text size values dynamically

```
<style name="TextInput" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
</style>
```

I want to change @color/colorPrimary and 50sp values through programatically

Comment: You cannot modify resources at runtime.

Comment: I think you should create two styles and change it when you want

Answer (score 0):

Your can use `<style name="TextInput" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">` hope to help you

Comment: i want to change values programatically.

Comment: you can change color file in src>main>res>values>colors.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use this for setting pragmatically textview and size color;

```
mProgressTV.setTextSize(float textViwSize);
mProgressTV.setTextColor(int color);
```